# LIKE Function in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, select, sql-like

Query the list of `CITY` names from the `STATION` table that do not start with vowels and do not end with vowels. Your result cannot contain duplicates.

https://www.hackerrank.com/challenges/weather-observation-station-12/problem

Using the `LIKE` operator I came up with 3 queries as follows :

Working

```
SELECT DISTINCT CITY 
FROM STATION 
WHERE CITY NOT LIKE '[aeiou]%' 
  AND CITY NOT LIKE '%[aeiou]'
```

Working

```
SELECT DISTINCT CITY 
FROM STATION 
WHERE CITY LIKE '[^aeiou]%[^aeiou]';
```

Not working:

```
SELECT DISTINCT CITY 
FROM STATION 
WHERE CITY NOT LIKE '[aeiou]%[aeiou]';
```

Can someone tell me why this third query is not working?

Comment: Does MySQL really support regexp in LIKE?

Comment: You are using ms sql server and not mysql as mysql's like operator does not support `^` and `[...]`.

Comment: It is really not necessary to put everything in **BOLD**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```sql
WHERE CITY NOT LIKE '[aeiou]%' 
  AND CITY NOT LIKE '%[aeiou]'
```

This query returns rows which **do not** start with a character that **is** a vowel and **do not** end with it.

This is essentially exactly the question as asked.

---

```sql
WHERE CITY LIKE '[^aeiou]%[^aeiou]';
```

This query returns rows which **do**: start with a character that **is not** a vowel **and also** end with a character that **is not** a vowel.

This is not quite the same, as it requires at least two characters, whereas the first version only requires a single one.

---

```sql
WHERE CITY NOT LIKE '[aeiou]%[aeiou]';
```

This query returns rows which **do not**: start with a character that **is** a vowel and also end with a character that **is** a vowel.

This is not *at all* the same as the previous queries. Another way of expressing it is: rows which **do** start with a non-vowel **or** end with it.

Comment: That's exactly what I wanted to understand.

Answer (score 1):

The third approach finds cities that don't start and end with a vowel. It will incorrectly return cities that start with a vowel but don't end with one, or cities that don't start with a vowel but do end with one.

Answer (score 0):

All your answers are incorrect!
This is it:

`select DISTINCT CITY from STATION where  CITY LIKE '[^aeiouAEIOU]%[^aeiouAEIOU]';`